# Editing a master template in domino

Tags: templates, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

We are developing an application which consumes the Domino Data Service. Hence, changes are being made to the several Views to enable for Data Service. As the application is inheriting from a master template, the properties which were changed are reverting to the original values periodically.

Is making the application a master template a valid option? Can we edit the master template from which it is inheriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Remove the "Inherit design from master template" and make your changes on the DB.
2. Modify the master template.

First option is my way of working then your transforme the changed DB to be a new master template [see](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_TEMPLATES_AND_MASTER_TEMPLATES_.html).

If you select the second option you will have to "application/Refresh Design" after each modification made in the template in order to test them in the DB.

Comment: is there a way to edit the master template. I'm not able to find the template 'StdR4PersonalAddressBook'

Comment: StdR4PersonalAddressBook is the standard template of the personnal address book. Look in the data directory for names.ntf.
Be aware that changing a standard template is problematic: when a new version is shipped you won't be abble to use this template since you MODIFIED your version. This is a common difficulty in Notes. I suggest putting the MODIFIED element in a SECOND template and inherit specifically this elements.